# Display mysql database query result on second pages

Tags: php, mysql

1. I have a mysql database with some data.here i display data on one page Now I want to display  this data on next page please give me suggestion how I can do this .........
   I need some modifications in this code like
   I want to display table this table on next page(book.php page  that is populated with the database)......
2. Second thing that I need to know is it possible to store the value of calendar in session variable (is it ???than how?)

```js
<?php
     
    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
     
    $query = mysql_query("select * from schedule where Destinatio='$from' AND     Arriva ='$to'");
     $c = mysql_num_rows($query);
     if (!$query) {
     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
     }
     if($c>0)
     {
     ?>
    <table>
    <tr align="center"><td width="120"><span class="style23">Destination</span>    </td>
    <td width="57"><span class="style23">Arrival</span></td>
    <td width="121"><span class="style23">Departure time</span></td>
    <td width="98"><span class="style23">Arrival Time</span></td>
    <td width="44"><span class="style23">Fare</span></td>
    <td width="85"><span class="style23">Bus_type</span></td>
    <td width="84"><span class="style23">Total_Seats</span></td>
    <td width="81"><span class="style23">Available</span></td>
    <td width="52">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </section>
    
    <?php
    while($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    $schedule= $r1['id'];
    $Destinatio = $r1['Destinatio'];
    $Arriva= $r1['Arriva'];
    $Departure_time = $r1['Departure_time'];
    $Arrival_time = $r1['Arrival_time'];
    $Fare = $r1['Fare'];
    $Bus_type = $r1['Bus_type'];
    $Total_Seats = $r1['Total_Seats'];
    $bust = $schedule.'schedule';
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * from $bust where status='Available'");
    echo $query1;
    if (!$query1) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    
    $c = mysql_num_rows($query1);
    ?>
    
    <tr align="center"><td><?php echo $Destinatio;?></td><td><?php echo $Arriva;?></td><td><?php echo $Departure_time;?></td><td><?php echo $Arrival_time;?></td><td><?php echo $Fare;?></td><td nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $Bus_type;?></td><td><?php echo $c;?></td><td><a href="book.php?id=<?php echo $uid;?>&bus=<?php echo $schedule;?>">Book</a>
     </td>
     </tr></table>
     </form>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sdl injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three main ways to pass variables:

1. Using a form button using $_POST variables to pass the content
   (generally best when you also have user input).
2. Using an HTML anchor link to pass the variables through $_GET
3. Using a SESSION variable that can be accessed on all pages on your site.

Using SESSION variables is the more secure way, but it the data isn't secret use the $_GET method.

To store something in a SESSION variable you need to use:

```
start_session();
$_SESSION['varname'] = value;
```

on the following page, you can read your SESSION variable just by using it's name. For example:

```
start_session();
echo $_SESSION['varname'];
```

Comment: Yes, absolutely. It is not really "passing it" though. SESSION variables are stored on the server and can be accessed through your PHP scripts. Will update my answer to show you how it's done.